# could not load class javax.rmi.corba.enum desc vmcid: omg minor code: 57 completed: maybe

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, glassfish-4

I'm trying to understand what exactly caused this exception. My project uses the glassfish4 server.

It is an ejb application. Problem happens when I inject a facade object into managed bean in web container (@EJB annotation is used to inject object) and I try get some data from database (entities).

Here is the stacktrace.

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException
at org.system.lib.facades._RoutesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.findAll(org/system/lib/facades/_RoutesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class javax.rmi.CORBA.EnumDesc  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.couldNotFindClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:983)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:813)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:806)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:796)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:544)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:389)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:542)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365)
at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:333)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1830)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1212)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:594)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1830)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1212)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:594)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1830)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1212)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2160)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2402)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:594)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1830)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1212)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:423)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:893)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:995)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:813)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:512)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:75)
at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.copyobject.impl.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:64)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObject(Util.java:770)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:245)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
at org.system.lib.facades.__RoutesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.findAll(org/system/lib/facades/__RoutesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
... 60 more
```

Comment: Dont make us afraid !

Comment: Why? If u a mean format of stactrace i cant do with this nothing beacuse i posted from mobile. Here cant do pretty format. Dont be a noob Man

Comment: A fix a little. Meaby now wilk be more readable

Comment: First type comments properly before typing noob and other things